# Class App\Http\Controllers\Requests\ArticleRequest does not exist Laravel5.3

Tags: php, laravel

Actually I'm very new of the php and Laravel5.3,and I have this problem when i want to set request of the form(Doing a simple blog page)

**ReflectionException in Route.php line 339: Class App\Http\Controllers\Requests\ArticleRequest does not exist**

And this is my controller code(Filename:ArticlesControllers.php):

```
 <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    //namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use App\Http\Requests\ArticleRequest;
    use App\Article;
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class ArticlesControllers extends Controller
    {
        //
        public function index(){
            $articles = Article::latest()->get();
            //return 'articles';
            return view('articles.index')->with('articles',$articles);
        }

        public function show($id){
            $article = Article::find($id);
    //        if(is_null($article)){
    //            abort(404);
    //        }
            //dd($artilce);
            return view('articles.show',compact('article'));
        }

        public function create(){
            return view('articles.create');
        }

        public function store(Requests\ArticleRequest $request){
            //dd($request->all());
            //接受post过来的数据
            //存入数据库
            //重定向
            $input=$request->all();

            //$input['published_at']=Carbon::now();
            Article::create($input);
            return redirect('/articles');
        }
    }
```

And the request File code:(Filename:ArticleRequest.php in the path Requests)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ArticleRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title'=>'required|min:3',
            'content'=>'required',
            'published'=>'require'
        ];
    }
}
```

My Route/Web.php is:

```
   <?php

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Web Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
    |
    */

    //Route::get('/','SiteController@index');


    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::get('/articles','ArticlesControllers@index');
    Route::get('/articles/create','ArticlesControllers@create');
    Route::get('/articles/{id}','ArticlesControllers@show');


    Route::post('/articles/store','ArticlesControllers@store');
```

How can i get rid of this nasty problem,I've been searching on StackOverFlow but nearly all the answers may not solve it....

Comment: are you create any authentication system for your project?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this to make it work:

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
```

Answer (score 0):

you already imported the class at the top

`use App\Http\Requests\ArticleRequest`

no need to use a full class name as an argument
just use

`public function store(ArticleRequest $request)`

or

`public function store(\App\Http\Requests\ArticleRequest $request)`

Comment: @charliefreak  Charlie, please mark this answer as the correct answer so people won't have to see this question because they are know that it's answered (and to give reputation to the people who give the correct answer) : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work